# Remove multiple attribute from jquery selectric

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectric

I need to allow multiple select sometimes, and sometimes not.
I try to remove the attribute and call init, but it still allow to select multi.

```
$('#dateSelect').removeAttr('multiple');
$('#dateSelect').selectric('init')
```

Comment: Can you post an example so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3mr9da53/

Answer (score 0):

Call 'destroy' solved my issue.

```
$('#Country').removeAttr('multiple');
$('#Country').selectric('destroy')
$('#Country').selectric('init')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/es69ys48/